# problem sending out emails using a cron job

Tags: php, cron

I basically have a normal php mail function script that is supposed to run every so often using a cron job, however some emails don't work when they actually work if I run the script manually.

for example in my hoshing cron control panel I enter in domain.ca/pear/Mail/test_mail.php

am I not entering in the url correct? Am I supposed to use some sort of cron job command

```
require_once('Mail.php');
require_once('../Mail_Mime/mime.php');


 $mail = Mail::factory("mail");

    $headers = array("From"=>"me@example.com", "Subject"=>"Test Mail");
    $body = "This is a test!";
    $mail->send("example@gmail.com", $headers, $body);
```

This is exactly my email script

Also, the cron works with certain email addresses like gmail.

So emails like my schools don't work in cron, but works when executed manually. Also the script updates the database using cron..

I have this in my .sh file :

```
/usr/local/nf/php5/bin/php -f ./test_mail.php
```

Comment: Does it send zero emails?  My hosting service limits the number of emails per hour, perhaps you are hitting a wall.

Comment: Also, have a look in the error log...

Answer (score 2):

You can't put the URL alone in a cron rule. Use text-based browser like `lynx` or `wget` in a cron rule:

`* * * * * wget http://mypage.com`

You might wish to add some parameters for `wget` or `lynx` so that it doesn't save outputs on server, instead just simulates the fetch. OR redirect output folder to `/tmp` or `/dev/null` for it to get wasted. Check man pages of related tool:

`man wget` OR `wget --help` via Shell.

YOU CAN ALSO do as Artefact2 recommends below: `* * * * * php script.php` . You may need to add shebang declaration for PHP at the top of your PHP codes tho:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// your PHP code here
```

Shebang needs to point to the working PHP executable in your system.

Comment: this control panel i've been provided has a field for www: and then I fill it in... The script runs, but the emails don't get sent

Comment: well, thats bad. you need to be sure the script runs at all... i mean, via cron.

Comment: Anyone can call this script from its browser, and also, it's messy. Just put `* * * * * php myscript.php` in your crontab.

Comment: sorry I don't know what that means. It's just weird because gmail works, but not my school's address. Now you're asking it must be my school's servers, however executing manually it will send the email. so, Cron will execute and update the database but not send the email to my school's email name.

Comment: What is your school domain name extension? .com? There might be some domain (or TLD) restriction in your server's MTA [mail transfer agent] config. Try other domains and make sure it works for them as well. If it does, contact the server admin...

Comment: As I said, if it works with all other domains, you have server-related issues. We can't solve those here... Make sure emails of other domains work (or not).

Comment: if .ca is restricted why does it work with no cron? I'm just trying to understand how cron works

Comment: yea weird. All the other emails work. Let's just say there are special spam filters at my school.. does cron leave a "mark" after sending?

Comment: Shell history file if I am not mistaken. Doesn't have to do anything with possible restriction.